# Why does my jQuery getJSON call (within Office.js (Excel js add-in)) return an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-js

This javascript within an Office js add-in always fails when making a get request:

```
function update() {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {

        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {

                var company = $('#company').val();
                var environment = $('#environment').val();
                var apiUrl = "https://localhost:44321/api/Country";
                var params = "company=" + company + "&environment=" + environment;

                $.getJSON(apiUrl, params)
                    .done(function (result) {
                        showNotification(result.length);
                    })
                    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                        //showNotification(error.statusText);
                        showNotification(error.length);
                    });
            });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        showNotification(error);
    });
}
```

I can see the json being returned successfully within Fiddler and JSONLint says the json is valid. Here it is:

[{"country":"UK","countryLongName":"United Kingdom","currency":"GBP"}]

I'm running on localhost with https, and have the following AppDomains in my manifest (belt and braces):

```
<AppDomain>https://localhost:44321/api/Country</AppDomain>
<AppDomain>https://localhost:44321</AppDomain>
<AppDomain>https://localhost</AppDomain>
```

However, getJSON.fail() is always invoked, with the following parameters:

- xhr.responseJSON: undefined
- xhr.statusText: "error"
- status: "error"
- error: ""

Why does getJSON always fail?

*Further edit*
I've tried this js instead...

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: apiUrl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    data: params,
                    success: function (data) {
                        showNotification(data);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        showNotification('error : ' + msg.d);
                    }
                });
```

...and now the error function is being invoked with the following parameters:

- msg.responseJSON: undefined
- msg.status: 0
- msg.statusText: "NetworkError"

Comment: Why do you think is failing?

Comment: Because I can break inside the .fail() and see that error is "error", status.responseJSON is undefined and statusText is "error".

Comment: I have also noticed I get similar results when using Michael Zlatkovsky's office.js demo (https://channel9.msdn.com/series/officejs/End-to-End-Walkthrough-of-Excel-JavaScript-Add-in-Development). Now wondering if it's an environment thing, perhaps VS2017?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. It isn't clear what error you're getting or where this error is being generated from.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've made some edits so hopefully it's now crystal clear what the error is?

Comment: Have you started by checking what the browser console has to say? Is the endpoint you are making this request to CORS-enabled? (Which it would have to be, if this is a cross-domain request as it looks like.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much, your comments got me to re-examine my server CORS config and do some digging, turns out services.AddCors needs to be *before* services.AddMvc(); see https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas#ApplythePolicy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all to do with CORS, I found the solution in rick-strahl's post:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas#ApplythePolicy

Specifically,
"UseCors() has to be called before UseMvc()
Make sure you declare the CORS functionality before MVC so the middleware fires before the MVC pipeline gets control and terminates the request."