# Excel web addin unable to complete GET request

Tags: office-js

I am creating an Excel web addin that needs to talk to an API (plumber api running behind nginx in a local container).

As a first try, I attempted a GET request to see how I would receive the results from the API.

My first attempt was to use $.getJSON (I also tried the ajax call directly):

```
  $.getJSON("https://localhost/textcat?txt=Wat%20gaan%20aan")
    .done(function(result) {
      writevalue(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    })
    .fail(function(error){
      writevalue(`err: ${error.statusText}`);
    })
```

My latestvattempt was to use axios:

```
axios.get('https://localhost/textcat?txt=hello')
.then(function(response){
  writevalue(`result: ${response}`);
})
.catch(function(error){
  writevalue(`result: ${error}`);
})
```

Both result in a "NetworkError"

[Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbGDm.png)

According to fiddler the API was reached and it did respond with my test response (Response: 200):
[Fiddler results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Posqh.png)

I realise that I must be missing something important, but I am just not seeing it. I would appreciate any insights or pointers that you might have.

Answer (score 1):

after posting this, and coming across a [similar question by Andrew Bennet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260161/why-does-my-jquery-getjson-call-within-office-js-excel-js-add-in-return-an-e), I managed to get a response in my WebApp.

The problem was CORS related.

My local plumber API is sitting on a docker container, hiding behind an NGINX instance. I had to configure NGINX to allow CORS with the following update to my nginx.conf file:

```
        location / {
      **if ($request_method = 'GET') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      }**
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8900/;
    }
```

Note: Only the If block was added. This also only applies to the GET method.

Catering for POST and OPTION methods are also shown here: https://serverfault.com/a/716283